# Angular : enum is undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, enums, frontend

I'm trying to use enum in angular but my enum object seems to be undefined.

**enum**

```
export enum Section {
    Equals="Equals",
    NEquals="NEquals",  
    }
```

**component**

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import { Section } from './model/Section.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-project'})


export class ProjectComponent implements OnInit {

    section = Section;
     
ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.section);
      }  
}
```

when I do `"console.log(this.section)"` the console displays undefined.
Any solutions please ?

Comment: I suppose you have to restart your `ng serve`. I remember the cli having issues picking up newly added enums

Comment: What you see when you log Section ?  `console.log(Section)`

Comment: @ArmenStepanyan it works when I use console.log(Section) but I want to use an object because I'll use it in a dropdown list. Any solutions ?

Comment: @PoulKruijt how to restart ng serve ?

Comment: @firas1 actually your code is correct, but try to move this line `section = Section` to `ngOnInit()`

Comment: Try to `console.log(Section.Equals)`

Comment: @firas1 as you can see [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jrqpzf) your code is working. So I suggest you alter the stackblitz and the question to your actual code where you have the issue you say you have

Answer (score 0):

We use a **TypeScript namespace** to add the **values() method** to the Section enum.

**You can see live demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-enum-example-xsfjnx)**

**section.enum.ts**

```
export enum Section {
  Equals = "Equals",
  NEquals = "NEquals"
}

export namespace Section {
  export function values() {
    return Object.keys(Section).filter(
      type => isNaN(<any>type) && type !== "values"
    );
  }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { Section } from "./section.enum";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: `
    <p>
      <select>
        <option *ngFor="let type of section.values()">
          {{ type }}
        </option>
      </select>
    </p>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  section = Section;
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(Section);
    console.log(Section.Equals);
    console.log(Section["Equals"]);
  }
}
```